# truncate all files recursively

Tags: files

can anybody give me a solution to enlarge all files of same extension by 264 bytes on entire hard disk? `truncate -s +264 /*encrypted` would enlarge all *.encrypted files by 264 bytes but only in one directory.

I want it to do the subfolders as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name "*.encrypted" -exec truncate -s +264 {} +
```

`find` will search in the `/path/to/directory` and all of its subdirectories for files with `.encrypted` extension and then run your desired `truncate` command over all of those found files.

If you want to search for the files in entire disk:

```
sudo find / -type f -name "*.encrypted" -exec truncate -s +264 {} +
```

If you are not sure about the names, don't run this one rather you should explicitly mention the directories (and its subdirectories) to search for, for example the following will find and execute the command over the only the files found in `/home/user` and `/tmp` directories (and their subdirectories):

```
find /home/user/ /tmp/ -type f -name "*.encrypted" -exec truncate -s +264 {} +
```

Note that you need to use `sudo` to search in the directories where you don't have required permission.

Comment: what does the trailing + at the end of the command do ?